# Wordpress: get page language in javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, location

How to get the language of a Wordpress page in Javascript?

I have found a way to check for Spanish:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/es/") > -1) {
```

But if the website is not with Permalink Settings with "Post name", the language preference will be with `?lang=es` in the URL.

And, can a Wordpress lang preference be "en-uk" for example?

Comment: Are you using a plugin for the language?

Comment: I would like a javascript way working for any Wordpress settings.

Comment: I figured, but that's not the question. You can output the language (and other settings) from WordPress into a `<script>` file in your document with [`wp_localize_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/).

Comment: This is a ` wp_localize_script` PHP function and I am looking for a Javascript way.

Comment: Yeah it outputs JavaScript in your document with values from PHP. Like the language value. Which you then can check in JavaScript by just accessing the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle a decent WordPress translation plugin would update the `<html>` tag with the apporpiate `lang` parameter, for instance, if language is set to American English:

```
<html lang="en-US">
... page code
</html>
```

Therefore, I think it would be much simpler using this function:

```
function getLanguage() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('lang');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with wordpress, but usually languages are set right after the domain name or as a url parameter. The function below handles both cases.

```
// tested with the following urls:
// url = 'domain.com/sdfsdf/dafsfd?lang=es';
// url = 'domain.com/sdfsdf/dafsfd?lang=es&sdfsf=dfsdf';
// url = 'domain.com/en-uk';
// url = 'domain.com/en-uk/';
// url = 'domain.com/en-uk?dfsdfsdf=dfsdf&sdfsfsdf=dfsdfs';

var url = window.location.href;
var lang = getLanguage(url);
console.log(lang);

function getLanguage(url) {
    // if language is set via url parameter
    if (url.includes('?lang=')) {
        return url.split('?lang=')[1].split('&')[0];
    }
    // if language is set via url route
    else {
        return url.split('/')[1].split('?')[0];
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly as:

```
const currentLanguage = document.documentElement.lang;
```